# Error running the SSIS package out side the Development studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am learning to work with the SSIS packages.

I have made an SSIS package to work with the delta data(changed data since last run).

But i am having troubles running the package outside the development enviroment

I have tried to runt it with `DTEXECUI.EXE` utilty but it gives me the following error.

[image]

I have also tried to run it from a stored procedure by enabling the **xp_cmdshell** but i still get some error like this.

[image]

Please help, i am also trying to Google my way through.

Comment: @Divi yes of course it runs in visual studio, after making a successfully running package. i tried to run it outside.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the error messages `To run a ssis package outside of sql server data tools you must...`

SSIS 2012 components have to be installed on your server to resolve the issue.

As per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/running-an-ssis-package-without-the-ssis-service-installed) post:

> What you need are the base SQL Server binaries which are installed
>   with the DB engine. So you need a SQL Server Instance of some flavour
>   to have dtexec running. Whether it's the DB Engine or the SSIS service
>   installed but disabled.
>
> Running packages in BIDS is a special case. Run the package on the
>   same PC as BIDS via dtexec and it will fail unless you have installed
>   server components (= a SQL Server Instance)

Comment: i am also trying to find these installation packages. got any link, +1

Comment: @Rex: Sorry, not really.

Comment: As @Divi suggested, you need to install SQL Server, so that you will have required binaries on machine.You can download and install SQL Server Express/Evaluation edition from here -  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/Try.aspx

Comment: Install SQL Server Step by Step guide - http://www.bu.edu/csmet/files/2013/01/SQL-Server-2012-Installation-Guide.pdf  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/basits-sql-server-tips/2012/06/23/sql-server-2012-installation-guide/

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde thanks vikram, I have Sql server Standerd edition installed on my machine. i am also able to make out that some components are missing. I Am just not able to find that component.:

Comment: You can use Discovery Report to check which components are been installed - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2013/06/13/sql-server-2012-discovery-report-determining-what-sql-server-components-are-installed.aspx